# Scrypt algorithm output doesen't match up as expected

Tags: bitcoin, mining, scrypt

I am trying to get my head around the scrypt algorithm output.

On https://litecoin.info/Block_hashing_algorithm the author gets the scrypt encryption result for the `headerString`:

`01000000ae178934851bfa0e83ccb6a3fc4bfddff3641e104b6c4680c31509074e699be2bd672d8 d2199ef37a59678f92443083e3b85edef8b45c71759371f823bab59a97126614f44d5001d45920180` [little endian]

to

`000000003b4ba52ab765631e20a04b88cd27f0b66d3509fb2da7781fae6d7901`. [big endian]

I'm trying to replicate this but im not able to reproduce that result. I'm using an implementation that gives the correct output for the test vectors in the end of this paper: http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt/scrypt.pdf but when running the `headerString` through it with the correct settings for N,r,p(1024,1,1) i get the result

`c17fcd0c6d698828112ade740d4e8ad76705764da3abfc49ff3bb1863cd16472`. [big endian]

I have tried it with the same result those implementations with the same result from both:

```
data = "01000000ae178934851bfa0e83ccb6a3fc4bfddff3641e104b6c4680c31509074e699be2bd672d8 d2199ef37a59678f92443083e3b85edef8b45c71759371f823bab59a97126614f44d5001d45920180";

    https://github.com/cheongwy/node-scrypt-js
var result = scrypt(data,data, 1024,1,1,32);

    https://github.com/tonyg/js-scrypt
var result = scrypt.crypto_scrypt(scrypt.encode_utf8(data), scrypt.encode_utf8(data), 1024, 1, 1, 32);
```

Im after the scrypt call im just parsing the byte array to a hex string if needed

Am I missing something here? I just can't understand why I am not getting the same result when I have validated my scrypt implementation against the paper about it.

I really need help solving this! If i haven't provided enought information please ask and ill try my best to clear things out.

Comment: No way to know what you are doing wrong from the info you give us. Which implementation of scrypt do you use? Using 4 test vectors is certainly not enough to find all possible implementation errors. Also, can you show us your call to the scrypt function?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have added the implementations ive been testing and the call i do to the scrypt functions. I hope this helps.

Comment: you input your data as a char array while it should be interpreted as a number (in hexadecimal representation)

Comment: Thank you verry much! It was so simple but i wasnt looking at the obvious and was digging in the implementation to find whats wrong.. Thank you! Its working great now =) Post an answer to this question so i can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you input your data as a char array while it should be interpreted as a number (in hexadecimal representation).